# Is it possible to use http get and http post in NSIS?

Tags: http, post, get, nsis, auto-update

I have a local updater that is able to download a mini installer from the web server using the NSISdl plugin.

Let's say I have a bunch of mini installer versions. Is there also a way for the local installer to check for the "LATEST" mini installer available from the web server . I've heard you can do that through a web service (by using http post or get). But is it possible with NSIS too? if it's possible how?

Thanks... I would appreciate your help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, one way is to just store the latest version in a file on your server.

Make a .ini with a format like:

```
[latestver]
major=2
minor=3
build=3452
```

Then just download this with InetC or NSISdl to $pluginsdir (Just a simple HTTP GET to http://yourserver.com/product/update.ini or something like that) and use the built-in INI functions and compare the version

Or you could script the whole thing server side by GET'ing a url like http://yourserver.com/versioncheck.php?product=foo&ver=1.2.333 and return the update url or a failure code